# Flutter internationalization intl_translate

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a new language to flutter since it is not supported by default.

I have added translated language file material_dv.arb to flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n and ran the code `dart dev/tools/gen_localizations.dart --overwrite` to generate localizations and date localizations dart file but still when i try to change the locale to the newly added locale dv an error comes up saying that the locale is not supported.  So what am i doing wrong here. Or how do i proceed to add a new language to flutter..

Comment: here is nice article for the same https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/internationalization---make-an-flutter-application-multi-lingual/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Localizations` class combined with a `LocalizationDelegate`:

```
   class MyLocalizations {
   MyLocalizations(this.locale);

   final Locale locale;

   static Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localizedValues = {
     'en': {
       'Title': 'App',
      },
     'ar': {
       'Title' : 'التطبيق',
      },
   };

   String translate(key) {
     return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode][key];
   }

   static String of(BuildContext context, String key) {
   return Localizations.of<MyLocalizations>(context,
    MyLocalizations).translate(key);
   }
 }
```

Then the `LocalizationDelegate`:

```
  class MyLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MyLocalizations> {

  const MyLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en', 'ar'].contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<MyLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return SynchronousFuture<MyLocalizations> (MyLocalizations(locale));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(MyLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

The complete guide to how to implement internationalization in your app in much easier way in in this [article](https://medium.com/saugo360/managing-locale-in-flutter-7693a9d4d6ac) which the above code snippet is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. But i have already implemented this part and its working for english and all other currently supported languages by flutter, but the problem is that my language is not yet supported. Here are currently supported langs (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n) and these localization files provide text for copy/paste/cancel like things...

Comment: The process I mentioned above doesn't need any localization files. You just have to provide the keyword and translations in above mentioned class and then call it using the `of` function.

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try.. Thank you

Comment: Not at all, if anything stopped hit back.